# Get Previous Data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the value of the previous data value inside the button. For example, when I click the row 2, I need to get the data value of the row 1. How can I do that?

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>act</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>tdornton</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
// THIS IS HOW I GET THE CLICKED ROW DATA
var rowid = $(this).data("rowid");
```

**Note** Usign the code of user Rory. When a user click in the first row, it get a "undefined". I updated the code with this condition, but im not solving the problem. As you can see, when i click row 2, im getting the row id 2 but no the 1, i need both. I think im getting problems in the condition.

```
    if ($prevButton === undefined)
    {
        var rowid = $(this).data("rowid"); 
        console.log(rowid);
    }
    else
    {
    var $button = $(this);
    var $prevButton = $button.closest('tr').prev().find('button');
    console.log('Prev button: ' + $prevButton.data('rowid'));               
    }
```

Comment: You could just give each button an id and use that

Comment: Which data value you want, `data-rowid` ?

Comment: What is `this`?

Comment: @satpal https://twitter.com/bendhalpern/status/578925947245633536?lang=en

Comment: you can handle it for the first element, what should be the output for it ?, below all answers can achieve you the remaining.

Comment: Given the edit you've just made, whats your question now?

Comment: i updated the question, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use DOM traversal to find the button in the previous row, using a combination of `closest()`, `prev()` and `find()`, something like this:

```js
$('.table button').click(function() {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $prevButton = $button.closest('tr').prev().find('button');
  
  if ($prevButton.length)
    console.log('Prev button: ' + $prevButton.data('rowid'));

  console.log('This button: ' + $button.data('rowid'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>act</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value-01">button</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>tdornton</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value-02">button</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td><button data-rowid="value-03">button</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Helo Rory, i think your code is the most according to the problem, i updated the post with a codition needed.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to check if the `$prevButton` exists? If so, check the `length` property instead, as a jQuery object is never null or undefined. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Does my update not solve the problem for you? Please be clear about what you expect to happen

Comment: Yes, it solve the problem except when a user click the first row, thats why the code need a condition when get a "undefined"

Comment: Right, but I updated my code to fix that. Does it still not work?

Answer (score 0):

via jQuery

```
$('tr').click(function(){
   console.log($(this).prev('tr').find('button').data('rowid'));
});
```

Comment: I was typing exactly same answer :) prev, find, data :)

Comment: first tr won't have prev.

Comment: Hello JaxCze, im trying your code and i get udefined, by the way bhansa is right

Comment: @osmelg you can put a condition for first element, and use the code for other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block:

```js
$('button[data-rowid="value"]').click(function(){
  var previousTr = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
  if(previousTr.length !== 0){
     var dataValue = $(previousTr).find('td button').data('rowid');
     console.log(dataValue);
  }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>act</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>tdornton</td>
          <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td><button data-rowid="value">button</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```